# How to sort a list with struct data in python like this?

Tags: python, sorting

I define a struct by class like this:

```
  class image:
  def __init__(self):
      self.address = ''
      self.label = 1
      self.storage = 1
```

Then, I put 100 stuct data into one list.

```
images = []
for i in range(100):
    single_image = image()
    single_image.address = 'xxx'
    single_image.label = 3 #1:5
    single_image.storage = 10 #1:100
```

How can I sort images by the storage?

Comment: This isn't a struct, is just a simple class.

Answer (score 4):

Use `operator`

```
import operator
images.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('storage'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator  
images_sorted = sorted(images,key=operator.attrgetter('storage'))
```

or you can sort images in place.

```
images.sort(images,key=operator.attrgetter('storage'))
```